# How to make window and all its elements resizable

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I have looked at QVBox and QHBox layouts as well as QGrid and QBox and I am attempting to have it so that it does not have restrictions so that I can set a button to any height or with a multiple of 2,5,10.

I am trying to have a window like so:[image]

The only way I can think of is to maybe have a QGrid with each column and row 10pc thick or something like that and have 2,000 to 3,000 rows and columns, is there a better way to do this.

Comment: The rows and columns of QGridLayout are not "physical" rows and columns, so having thousands of them is pointless and useless. Just learn to properly use spacers and [stretch factors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors).

Comment: so what i have gathered from the stretch factors is that they assign how much space is given in a QHBoxLayout but how do they do this, what do the number passef into it actually do

Comment: It's written in the description: they are proportional. If you assign a factor of 2 to element x and a factor of 3 to element y, the available space is divided by 5 (the sum of stretch factors) and assigned according to each factor: if the available size is 100, then x will be 40 and y 60, assuming no other stretch factor is set, and considering the minimum size, hint and policy of each element.

Comment: So then, if the window is resized to 200, x is 80 and y is 120, is this the same for both width and height and if how does that work. Would it work for two different types of widget e.g. a Button and LineEdit.

Comment: As said, it depends on the element size restraints, hints and policies. Each widget type has different ways of dealing with sizes, and layout can also have spacers or even other nested layouts. It's all written in the documentation, so please take your time to carefully read the *whole* link above and all the documentation of each widget type you're going to use, then also consider using Designer to play around with all these aspect in order to better understand how they work.

Comment: I've read the documentation and played around with it but I can't seem to make make it affect the height of widgets, horizontally the widget change but vertically they don't. However, the main problem is that with a horizontal layout I can only make one row and with a vertical layout I can only make one column.